# Reading method name from excel sheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want to read a method from excel sheet and concatenate it with Class here is my code

```
book = Spreadsheet.open 'path/to/myexcel'
book.worksheets
sheet1 = book.worksheet 'Sheet1'
tcname = sheet1.cell(1,0)
TestCases.new.tcname
```

the problem with concatenation .. anyone have any ideas how to concatenate this variable?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `TestCases.new` returns a string:

```
"#{TestCases.new}#{tname}" # this is technically interpolation
```

or

```
TestCases.new + tname # this is concatenation
```

or

```
[TestCases.new, tname].join # this is also concatenation
```

All 3 should have the same result.

[EDIT]

Based on the comment you posted, it also seems to me that maybe what you are actually asking, is how to use the value of `tcname` as a method to send to an instance of TestCases.

If that is the case, you can do:

```
TestCases.new.send(tcname)
```

Though if the source of the spreadsheet cannot be trusted, this is bad security-wise, better to pick from a pre-approved whitelist of available methods like so:

```
available_methods = ['upcase', 'name', 'to_sentence', 'Login_Click']
method_to_call = available_methods.detect{|m| m == tcname }
TestCases.new.send(method_to_call) if method_to_call
```

Comment: thank u for your quick reply , but TestCases.new  is not a string its a class object to call tcName which is method that are pulled from excel sheet ,, ( example  tcname = Login_Click)

Comment: @user3368238 Ah, misunderstood. Edited question to address that case :)

Comment: i tried this but it keeps give me this error uninitialized constant Object::TestCases (NameError)

Comment: `TestCases.new` is what you called it in the question. It appears this class does not exist. Maybe you meant `TestCase.new` (singular)?

Comment: no its TestCases and when i type the method "Login_Click" it works( TestCases.new.Login_click) ,, but when i add tcName which is supposed to store Login_click it gives me this error

Comment: When you say "I add tcName", do you mean you are calling `TestCases.new.tcName`. Is the `tcName` method defined in that class (or an attribute on an ActiveRecord class)?

Comment: as i said above i added                      
tcname =sheet1.cell(1,0)  
TestCases.new.send(tcname)
tcname is the attirbute that i read from excel sheet

Comment: The NameError means you tried to call a method that doesn't exist on the instance of `TestCase.new`, so whatever is in `tcname` isn't a valid method name. Capitialization must match.